# Can any character be encoded in UTF-16 (using Java 8)

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16

Can any character be encoded in UTF-16 (using java) ?

I thought it could but my code that encodes as

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE").newEncoder();
ByteBuffer bb = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap((String) value + '\0'));
```

has thrown a CharacterCodingException

Unfortunately as this only occurred for a customer not myself I dont have details of the offending character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possible values of `char` that are not valid UTF-16 sequences. For example:

```
    CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE").newEncoder();
    ByteBuffer bb = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("\uDFFF"));
```

This code will throw an exception. U+DFFF is an [unpaired surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF).

Comment: have I got this right DFFF is not a valid unicode character and cannot be encoded because of this http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2013-m01/0201.html .But any actual unicode character could be encoded.

Comment: Or is that it is a unicode char (though more of a metacharcter) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=DFFF&preview=entity but cannot be encoded as UTF-16 because of the way UTF-16 works (i.e. its almost like a reserved word)

Comment: The Unicode set is larger than a 16-bit value can contain. Some code _points_ require two code _units_ in the UTF-16 scheme. For example, U+1D50A is represented as the two-char surrogate pair sequence `"\uD835\uDD0A"`. However, encoding `"\uD835"` or `"\uDD0A"` individually isn't meaningful.

Comment: Note that it is possible to change the behaviour of your encoder using [onMalformedInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#onMalformedInput-java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction-) and [onUnmappableCharacter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#onUnmappableCharacter-java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction-)

Comment: okay thanks that is what ive done to just ignore these rare ocurrences